# alignment problem with the + sign in chemfig (zero width arrow)

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig

I created two molecules in chemfig and would like to place a + mark vertically aligned in the middle between the two molecules. There is an example of this demonstrated in the manual (see the code), but i'm unable to reproduce it using my own alignment.

How can I achieve the result I wanted (also tikz hacks are welcome, althought I prefer to stay within chemfig)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
%my molecules, the + sign should be alligned in middle just as the manual example
\schemedebug{true}
\schemestart[][west]
\chemname{\chemfig{C(=O)(-[4]H)-[6]C(-H)(-[4]OH)-[6]CHOH}}{\footnotesize{L-glyceraldehyde}}
\arrow{0}[,0]\+
\chemname{\chemfig{COO\textsuperscript{-}-[6]C(=O)-[6]CH}}{\footnotesize{pyruvate}}
\schemestop

\bigskip
%example taken from the chemfig manual (page 67)
% + sign is correctly aligned to the middle.
\schemedebug{true}
\schemestart[][west]
\chemfig{C(<[:40])(<[:160])=[6]C(<[:-130])<[:-20]}
\arrow{0}[,0]\+
\chemfig{\lewis{246,Br}-\lewis{026,Br}}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

Comment: The code does not compile.

Comment: For me it does, althought I do get quite some missing } errors.

Comment: `chemfig` atoms already are in math mode so remove the `$`.

Comment: @Timtico That's what I said: if the LaTeX run throws up errors, then the file doesn't compile.

Comment: You're also going to need a class like `article` instead of `minimal` to make the code compilable

Comment: I used the minimal class since I thought it was common sense here. It compiles for me. The document I use chemfig in is an article class.

Comment: @Timtico Never use the `minimal` class. See [this question in Meta](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2383/which-documentclass-is-best-to-use-in-mwes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply insert a second invisible arrow and maybe use the optional arguments of `\+{<dim1>,<dim2>,<dim3>}` (where `<dim1>` is a horizontal space before the plus `<dim2>` a horizontal space after the plus and `<dim3>` a vertical shift) to adjust the plus vertically

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\schemestart
\chemname{\chemfig{C(=O)(-[4]H)-[6]C(-H)(-[4]HO)-[6]CH_2OH}}{\footnotesize{L-glyceraldehyde}}
\arrow{0}[,0]\+{,,1.5em}\arrow{0}[2,0]
\chemname{\chemfig{COO^{-}-[6]C(=O)-[6]CH_3}}{\footnotesize{pyruvate}}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: amazing! thanks you for that super fast answer!

Comment: and now I understand the trick aswell, debug view shows me the + sign is now properly turned into it's own compound.

Answer (score 3):

A better solution is to start the `chemfig` code of `L-glyceraldehyde` with the middle "H" and to start the one of `pyruvate` with the middle "C". Then, you don't need the `\arrow{0}` trick and you don't need to adjust the vertical position of `\+`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\schemestart
\chemname{\chemfig{H-[4]C(-[6]CH_2OH)(-[4]HO)-[2]C(-[4]H)=O}}{\footnotesize{L-glyceraldehyde}}
\+
\chemname{\chemfig{C(=O)(-[6]CH_3)-[2]COO^{-}}}{\footnotesize pyruvate}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image: chemfig]

Comment: thanks for the tip. Yes that indeed works fine, it's abit less intuitive (especially when building sugars starting from glyceraldehyde) but I will give it a try.